# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: invalid locator

Tags: xpath, automation, appium, appium-android

I am trying to do hybrid app testing using Appium. I am trying to get the element by the xpath. But I am facing the following issue.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.166)
```

This is my html taken from chrome developer option.

```
<mat-select _ngcontent-anp-c247="" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="none" aria-haspopup="true" data-mx-id="mx-cb-20101-slt-choosecompany" class="mat-select ng-tns-c85-113 ng-tns-c60-112 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" aria-labelledby="mat-form-field-label-45 mat-select-value-33" id="mat-select-32" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" aria-required="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" xpath="1"><div cdk-overlay-origin="" class="mat-select-trigger ng-tns-c85-113"><div class="mat-select-value ng-tns-c85-113" id="mat-select-value-33"><!----><span class="mat-select-value-text ng-tns-c85-113 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="mat-select-min-line ng-tns-c85-113 ng-star-inserted"> India Pvt Ltd</span><!----><!----></span><!----></div><div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c85-113"><div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c85-113"></div></div></div><!----></mat-select>
```

I created the xpath like:

```
//*[contains(@data-mx-id,'mx-cb-20101-slt-choosecompany')]
```

When I paste this xpath in chrome dev options the element location is showing perfectly.

When I try with Appium inspector the element location is showing perfectly.

But when I try from Appium-Selenium code I am getting `invalid argument: invalid locator` exception.

I switched to webview context by the following code.

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String context : contextNames) {
            if (context.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                System.out.println("Context Name is " + context);
                driver.context(context);
                break;
            }
        }
```

This is how I take element by xpath
@AndroidFindBy(xpath ="//*[contains(@data-mx-id,'mx-cb-20101-slt-choosecompany')]")
public WebElement testSpinner;

If I give the full xpath it's working fine. But I should not use full xpath as per appium suggestion.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `chromeOptions` capability like the following.

For Java:

```
setCapability("chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
```

For Python:

```
chromeOptions={"w3c": False}
```